# iterate through vector with for loop in c++

Tags: c++

I am reading a tutorial about joystick input handling with SDL and I am struggling with a part of the code.

In .h file I got:

```
std::vector<std::pair<Vector2D*, Vector2D*> > m_joystickValues;
```

and in .cpp file I got:

```
m_joystickValues.push_back(std::make_pair(new Vector2D(0,0),new Vector2D(0,0)));
```

In this case I have one joystick, if there is many joysticks there will more push_backs, I want to access the adresses in "m_joystickValues" so I can delete them in a clean function.

Anyone has an idea how I can do this with a for loop. Thanks

Comment: What's stopping your from the good ole' `for(int x=0; x<m_joystickValues.size(); x++)`?

Comment: If possible, change to `std::vector<std::pair<Vector2D, Vector2D>> m_joystickValues;` to have automatic memory management.

Comment: Use [`std::shared_ptr<Vector2D>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) and [`std::make_shared<Vector2D>()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) so there's no need for manual memory management.

Comment: Which part of writing a `for` loop are you having trouble with? Have you looked back at your textbook to remind yourself how they work?

Answer (score 4):

For example you can use the range-based for statement

```
for ( auto &p : m_joystickValues )
{
   delete p.first;
   delete p.second;
}
```

The same can be done using the ordinary for statement

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < m_joystickValues.size(); i++ )
{
   delete m_joystickValues[i].first;
   delete m_joystickValues[i].second;
}
```

Or you can use standard algorithm `std::for_each` with an appropriate lambda-expression. It is similar to using a for statement with iterators.

Comment: The iterator version is missing :-) (with `std::vector<std::pair<Vector2D*, Vector2D*>>::iterator` instead of `auto` ^^)

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 0; i < m_joystickValues.size(); i++)
{
    m_joystickValues[i] //do something with this
}
```

Is this what you are looking for? Also, you could use the `at` function, since it is more safe.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(auto& i : m_joystickValues)
{
    delete i.second;
    delete i.first; // or do whatever
}
```

At end of the loop you can erase the entire vector

```
m_joystickValues.erase(m_joystickValues.begin(), m_joystickValues.end());
```

Comment: You may use `m_joystickValues.clear();` instead of `erase` the whole range

Comment: @Jarod42 yes that's neater.